# Create virtual network interface on host bridged from Wireguard namespace

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, wireguard

I want to set up Wireguard in a way where I only route specific processes (like qBittorrent) through the tunnel, while other processes default to the physical interface. Since my VPN provider only seems to work when `allowed-ips` is set to `0.0.0.0/0`, I decided to set up the Wireguard interface inside a namespace using [this](https://gist.github.com/stvhay/9e37059abe96db5c7439323f55c373c0) example.

My initial setup script looks like this:

```
ip netns add tunnel0
ip link add wg0 type wireguard
ip link set wg0 netns tunnel0

ip netns exec tunnel0 wg set wg0 \
    private-key /etc/wireguard/wg0_privkey \
    peer <public_key> \
    endpoint x.x.x.x:51820 \
    allowed-ips 10.64.0.0/16,0.0.0.0/0
ip netns exec tunnel0 ip addr add 10.64.189.228/32 dev wg0 
ip netns exec tunnel0 ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0 
ip netns exec tunnel0 ip route add default dev wg0
```

This results in my setup looking [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szwuv.png).

As the title suggests, I want to create an interface (`vpn0`) on my host that is bridged from the Wireguard interface (`wg0`) inside the `tunnel0` namespace, which would let me choose that interface in an application like qBittorrent, without any other processes being routed through the tunnel. My setup would then look [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8avrL.png).

I have read somewhere that I would need to use something like VXLAN, however, since I am not very experienced in Linux networking, I have not managed to find any examples of what I am trying to specifically achieve.

Am I doing this right, or is there a much simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since my VPN provider only seems to work when allowed-ips is set to 0.0.0.0/0,

Yes, that's normal for VPNs, because you're using the tunnel to access the entire Internet, and you're expecting to receive reply packets from the entire Internet as well. Therefore, the tunnel needs to allow the peer to represent the entire Internet.

This doesn't make it necessary to use namespaces. The AllowedIPs setting on the `wg0` interface works as a filter, but *does not* actually grab and route all your IP traffic through that interface. It's more like a firewall rule.¹

In short, you can just do literally the same `wg0` configuration *without* namespaces, and then you wouldn't need to bridge anything because you already have the interface right here.

But instead of creating a global default route through wg0, put it in a different routing table using `ip -4 route add default dev wg0 table 3`, and use "policy routing" rules via `ip -4 rule add` to select that table only if a program tries to bind to the VPN address as the "source" address.

¹ (It's only the identically named *wg-quick* setting that also creates IP routes for all allowed prefixes, giving you a default route through the VPN which you don't want. But as you're not using wg-quick to create the tunnel, this shouldn't affect you – and even if you were using it, wg-quick also has an option to put the routes in a different routing table, or to not create them at all.)

Comment: I simplified my script so that the interface was created on the host, and then modified the default route line so that it was set to a different table (didn't know that existed), and when I select the wg0 interface in qBittorrent, it works perfectly without leaks! Thanks for the explanation of AllowedIPs as a firewall in that it doesn't necessarily have to hijack your entire IP range, a problem I had when using wg-quick before.

Comment: nitpicking: it does "route" between multiple WireGuard peers to figure out where to send outgoing packets, but only after the normal stack routes. As it's 0.0.0.0/0 there can be only one peer anyway (the provider). details there: https://www.wireguard.com/#cryptokey-routing